# Можno ли разобрать JSON в таблицу с непостоянной структурой данных?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

Eсть требование, получать файлы JSON, экспортированные из MongoDB, и загружать их в реляционные таблицы. Версия Oracle 12c, то есть есть возможность использовать функционал JSON.

Нет проблем, разобрать `CLOB` с JSON в таблицы, когда известна структура поступающих данных. Но источник данных непостоянен, и столбцы могут быть добавлены, перемещены или удалены в мгновение ока разработчиками. Нет никакого контроля или влияния на исходную систему, поэтому нельзя получить данные со стабильной структурой.

Что требуется, это взять полученный `CLOB` и загрузить данные в таблицу на основе структуры источника данных.

Возможно ли это сделать?

Известно, что можно командой `JSON_TABLE` преобразовать `CLOB` в табличную форму, но это требует знания структуры данных для загрузки в таблицу. Поскольку это должен быть автоматизированный процесс, то пытаюсь найти решение этой проблемы.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Can you parse a JSON String to an Table when you have a volatile data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49513299) от участника [@mwdownie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9558301/mwdownie)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49513299

Comment: JSON легко разбирается в иерархический EAV.

Comment: @Akina Буду рад, если вы добавите ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с версии 12.2, есть простой способ сделать это с помощью [JSON Data Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/json-dataguide.html#GUID-219FC30E-89A7-4189-BC36-7B961A24067C).

Это позволяет отображать атрибуты документа JSON как виртуальные столбцы в таблице. Чтобы воспользоваться им, необходимо:

- на столбце с данными должно быть ограничение `is json`
- поисковый индекс JSON с параметром `dataguide on`

```
create table t (doc clob check (doc is json));

insert into t values ('{"attr1": "value1"}');
    
create search index tsi on t (doc) for json 
    parameters ('dataguide on change add_vc');
```

Теперь можо добавлять виртуальные столбцы:

```
begin
    dbms_json.add_virtual_columns ('t', 'doc',
        dbms_json.get_index_dataguide('t', 'doc', dbms_json.format_hierarchical));
end;
/
select * from t;

DOC                   DOC$attr1   
{"attr1": "value1"}   value1
```

Что же делает параметр индекса `change add_vc`? С ним будут добавлены виртуальные столбцы в таблицу на основе вставленных документов при фиксации:

```
insert into t (doc) values ('{"attr2": "value2"}');
commit;

select * from t;
    
DOC                   DOC$attr1   DOC$attr2   
{"attr1": "value1"}   value1      <null>      
{"attr2": "value2"}   <null>      value2
```

Разумеется, что это добавит некоторые временные затраты каждый раз, когда идёт вставка новых данных. Поэтому, может лучше не использовать `change add_vc` при поступлении новых данных, а запланировать задание на добавление столбцов.

Если в итоге окажется, что много устаревших атрибутов, которые надо игнорировать, то можно легко избавиться от виртуальных столбцов с помощью вызова процедуры:

```
exec dbms_json.drop_virtual_columns ('t', 'doc');
    
select * from t;
    
DOC
------------------------
{"attr1": "value1"}
{"attr2": "value2"}
```

Все это работает для скалярных атрибутов. А как насчет массивов?
К сожалению, они не будут отображаться как виртуальные столбцы:

```
insert into t (doc) values ('{"attr3": ["value3", "value4"]}');
commit;
    
select * from t;
    
DOC
--------------------------------
{"attr1": "value1"}
{"attr2": "value2"}
{"attr3": ["value3", "value4"]}
```

Тогда можно создать представление, которое отобразит их:

```
begin 
    dbms_json.create_view ('tv', 't', 'doc',
        dbms_json.get_index_dataguide ('t', 'doc', dbms_json.format_hierarchical));
end;
/
select * from tv;

DOC$attr1   DOC$attr2   DOC$attr3             
value1      <null>      <null>                
<null>      value2      <null>                
<null>      <null>      ["value3","value4"]
```

При добавлении новых атрибутов представление не будет автоматически обновляться, но его можно легко перестроить:

```
insert into t (doc) values ('{"attr4": ["value5", "value6"]}');
commit;

select * from tv;

DOC$attr1   DOC$attr2   DOC$attr3             
value1      <null>      <null>                
<null>      value2      <null>                
<null>      <null>      ["value3","value4"]   
<null>      <null>      <null>  

begin
    dbms_json.create_view ('tv', 't', 'doc',
        dbms_json.get_index_dataguide('t', 'doc', dbms_json.format_hierarchical));
end;
/
select * from tv;

DOC$attr1   DOC$attr2   DOC$attr3             DOC$attr4             
value1      <null>      <null>                <null>                
<null>      value2      <null>                <null>                
<null>      <null>      ["value3","value4"]   <null>                
<null>      <null>      <null>                ["value5","value6"]
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49514509) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>